# Chrome DevTools Network requests payload arrows from JSON objects are out of place

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Not sure if this is only affecting me but, as shown in the attached picture, my object arrows are our of place making it very hard to read the object.

They should be on the same line as the property as shown in picture

[image]

Comment: You are not alone, this is very very annoying. as per https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1359297&q=payload seems like the fix is merged for 106 release
"Please merge to M106 asap as I will be cutting M106 RC tomorrow" (9/20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue here.
Not sure which version, but i confirm it **has been fixed** in `Chrome 106.0.5249.91 official release`

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a regression bug. There is an open issue in the Chromium issue tracker here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1359297&q=payload

Answer (score 0):

if do you still face this annoying issue,
just update to the last Version,
it has been fixed recently.